# How to run two parallel scripts in Shell but wait on a "middle" script to exit

Tags: shell-script

I want to:

1. Run a script which never exits, this will produce a file
2. Run a script which watches for this file and then exits
3. Run the final script which also never exits (which depends on the first one's output)

I've seen this answer: [Run commands in parallel and wait for one group of commands to finish before starting the next](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242087/run-commands-in-parallel-and-wait-for-one-group-of-commands-to-finish-before-sta) but I don't think my requirements are the same since the first script will never exit.

```
# This runs continuously
nps $DEV_SCRIPT &

# How can I not run the final parallel script until this exits?
node ./scripts/waitForAssetManifest.js &
wait

# This also runs continuously
node-dev build/lib/index.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_0021) to get the pid of a job just after it’s been placed in the background, and wait for that process specifically:

```bash
# This runs continuously
nps $DEV_SCRIPT &

# How can I not run the final parallel script until this exits?
node ./scripts/waitForAssetManifest.js &
wait $!

# This also runs continuously
node-dev build/lib/index.js
```

In this specific scenario you might as well not run the second command in the background:

```
# This runs continuously
nps $DEV_SCRIPT &

# How can I not run the final parallel script until this exits?
node ./scripts/waitForAssetManifest.js

# This also runs continuously
node-dev build/lib/index.js
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Also realised the answer I linked to works as I can do `parallel1 & { waitCommand && parallel2 }` oops